# How to create jQuery functions?

Tags: jquery

I have seen a few different approaches to create jQuery(-namespaced) functions, but I cannot quite tell the actual difference between them.

`jQuery.fn.myFunction = function() { ... };`

`jQuery.myFunction = function() { ... };`

`jQuery.fn.extend({ myFunction: function() { ... } });`

Answer (score 6):

`jQuery.fn.myFunction` is what you use to create functions that will be available on every jQuery result set:

```
$('div').myFunction();
```

`jQuery.myFunction` is what you use to create helper functions that are just available on the jQuery object, such as `$.inArray`

Your last version extends the `$.fn` object with a new function, and is as such the functional equivalent of your first example.