# how to attach/extend methods to dom element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having this html:

```
<div id='hi1'> aaa </div>
```

When doing:

```
$('#hi1').sayHi();
```

I would like to get an alert saying 'hi'

anybody knows how this is done ?

Comment: Why not just `$.sayHi()`? Why should it be tied to DOM elements if you're not going to use it? :)

Comment: @Jack I suspect Chuck is giving an over-simplified example.

Comment: Your HTML is wrong. You are closing your `div` twice!

Comment: This is not attaching a method to DOM, its extending jQuery.

Comment: @Amberlamps only if it is xhtml, in html5 it's okay.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create jQuery functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334364/how-to-create-jquery-functions)

Comment: @lanzz: Seriously? That just looks wrong :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.fn.sayHi = function() {
    alert($(this).text());
    return this;
};

$('#hi1').sayHi();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/TyTYy/1/)**

Read more about **[jQuery Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)**

Answer (score 4):

Read more about [jQuery plugin authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

Answer (score 2):

```
$.fn.extend({ sayHi:function(){ alert('hi'); });
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery methods aaaaw yeah!

```
jQuery.fn.sayHi = function() {
  // this is the jQuery object
  // so this[0] is a DOM element (or undefined)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually want to create your own method (plugin) called: `.sayHi()`

### *[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/nZEBN/)*

```
$.fn.sayHi = function(something){   
    alert(something);       
};

$('#hi1').sayHi('hi');    // 'hi' will be passed to the jQuery method 'sayHy'
```

More info here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Another example:

```
$.fn.sayHi = function(txt, clr){   
     this.css({color: clr}).text(txt); // 'this' is your element delegated to your plugin
};

$('#hi1').click(function(){   
    $(this).sayHi('Heading is clicked!', 'red');  // (txt, crl)                                
});
```

### *[demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/nZEBN/3/)*